# Check visibility of the child process window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I have two .NET applications:

1. `parent-app.exe` (*WPF*)
2. `child-app.exe` (*WinForms*)

The first application starts the second one

### `parent-app.exe` →  `child-app.exe`

by means of the class [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx).

When user clicks a button on the interface of the `parent-app.exe`, I start the process of `child-app.exe` *immediately*. Because `child-app.exe` is a .NET application, is takes some time before user could see the window (especially, on slow systems).

I want to show the user an intermediate (possibly dialog) window from `parent-app.exe`. This dialog window should say that user action is being processed and he should wait for the window of `child-app.exe` to show up.

---

### Questions:

> - How can I check from `parent-app.exe` ***visibility state*** of the window of `child-app.exe`?
> - Here is the longer question. How would you implement this system of showing intermediate window by taking into account the restriction
>     that both programs use .NET?

Comment: Progress bar + disabled button ?

Comment: I updated my answer to accommodate for the new info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=vs.110).aspx), you can try calling the `Process.WaitForInputIdle` method to wait for the `MainWindowHandle` to be created or periodically calling `Process.Refresh` and check if `MainWindowHandle` returns a valid handle. Perhaps this is enough for you, otherwise you can get additional information with the handle. In WinForms you could probably do something like this:

```
Form window = (Form)Control.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
```

I suspect there are similar solutions for other frameworks.

**Update**

I wrote this small sample, it is untested and I don't know if it works reliably (it may deadlock), but it should hint at some things you can try:

```
namespace SomeNS
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public static class SomeClass
    {
        static void SomeMethod()
        {
            Process process = Process.Start("child-app.exe");
            // YourDialog is your dialog implementation inheriting from System.Windows.Window
            YourDialog dlg = new YourDialog();
            dlg.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
            {
                process.WaitForInputIdle();
                Form window = (Form)Control.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
                // Do something with the child app's window
                dlg.Close();
            };
            dlg.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the function [WaitForInputIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms687022(v=vs.85).aspx) is just what I needed. Thank you!